# Importing third-party library source files into Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I've got a project set up very nicely with eclipse-cdt. I'm not building from eclipse, but the indexer works and all my makefile settings were picked up, including third party libraries headers.

What I would like, however, is to be able to view the actual source of those libraries - say, if I want to see some code in Qt or libc I'd like to be able to CTRL+click into the method from the relevant header file. You can do this in the java version of eclipse, whenever you are missing a source file, you have an option of  "attaching source". I've looked everywhere with CDT and can't find a solution. I don't want to build these third party libs, I just want to be able to click-through to their source code, not only to their headers.

Does anyone know how to do this (am I missing something obvious)?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, found the answer.
In the Project's Properties window, under "C/C++ General" there is a tab called "Source Location", your project's folder should be listed there. Click on "Link Folder", mark the "Link to Folder in the file system" and use "Browse" to find the folder where all he library's source code is.

Comment: This seems to no longer be valid, any idea what the new setting should be?

Comment: Eclipse Luna: Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> tab Source Location. As an alternative: New Folder -> click Advanced -> choose Link to alternate location.